# Best practice to control the flow on a ZMQ Streamer device?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

Imagine I have a streaming device like the one in the bellow template.

[image: Architechture]

image from [here](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/devices/streamer.html)

```
def worker(backend_port):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % backend_port)
    while True:
        task = socket.recv()
        # do something

def streamer(frontend_port):# it's called streamer because streams files from hdfs
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % frontend_port)
    while True:
        #  get the file
        #  prepare it
        socket.send(msg, copy=False)

number_of_workers = 16
number_streamers = 10

frontend_port = 7559
backend_port = 7560

streamerdevice  = ProcessDevice(zmq.STREAMER, zmq.PULL, zmq.PUSH)
streamerdevice.bind_in("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % frontend_port )
streamerdevice.bind_out("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d" % backend_port)
streamerdevice.setsockopt_in(zmq.IDENTITY, b'PULL')
streamerdevice.setsockopt_out(zmq.IDENTITY, b'PUSH')
streamerdevice.start()

for i in range(number_of_workers):
    p = Process(target=yolo, args=(backend_port,))
    p.start()

for i in range(number_streamers):
    s = Process(target=streamer, args=(frontend_port,))
    s.start()
```

To give more information messages are images so are on the bigger size. I am using zero-copy. Performance is the most important point in my case since I am running on a very big scale.

- Is there a way to multi-thread that `streamerdevice`?
- **How can I control the flow? is there a way to know how many messages are waiting to get processed?**
- one of the main goals is to make the receiving time as fast as possible on the worker side. Any suggestions for that?
- Does it help to start the `zmq.Context(nIoTHREADs)` for `nIoTHREADs`>1 in `worker` side?

---

Comment: There's not enough specific information here to provide a specific answer.  Yes, image files, being larger, are likely to reduce the total throughput of the system.  The easiest way to run this in a multi-threaded way is to spin up a new socket per thread.  But we'd need to know a lot more about what you're doing to suggest a viable communication architecture.  Without that, all we can do is provide suggestions on your actual code, which you haven't provided.  So, as-is, this is way to broad for SO.

Comment: I added more information and a code snippet to make it more clear. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score -1):

> How to run a multi-threaded ZMQ device?

The simplest way to run multi-threaded ZeroMQ services is to instantiate the respective **`zmq.Context( nIoTHREADs )`** for `nIoTHREADs > 1`. There are more performance tweaking configuration options for scaling performance. Review the `pyzmq` wrapper, how does this ZeroMQ tooling apply to actual the `pyzmq` wrapper code and ask maintainers, whether their setup and/or configuration remained fixed or just unpublished with this regard. ZeroMQ is flexible enough to provide means for doing this.

> ...device (which is a one way queue) is not scalable as you increase the number of input connections

Well, a device is neither a one way queue, nor is not scalable. Right the very opposite.

> Is it possible to run it in a multi-threaded way?

Sure it is.

> what is the best way to scale it?

That depends a lot on exact messaging and signaling requirements that your system design ought meet. High volume, ultra-low latency, almost linear scaling, adaptive connection handing, app-domain user-defined protocols are just a few of such properties to take into account.

> Is it because the queue gets so big and that is why it gets slow?

The post contained zero pieces of information about neither the sizes, nor about any speed observations and/or expectations. In other, documented, test setups, ZeroMQ is known to be very cute in buffer-management, if zero-copy and other performance motivated approaches are used, so no one can help on a more detailed level.

> is there a way to know how big the queue is at any moment?

No, there is no such "built-in" feature, that would spend time and resources on counting this. If such add-on feature is needed in your system, you are free to add such add-on, without making other use-cases wear a single bit of such additional code for use-cases, where a message counting and queue-size reporting is meaningless.

> any load balancing strategy for the device without a `REQ-REP` pattern?

Yes, there are many ready-made Scalable Formal Communication Archetype Patterns plus there are scenarios one may compose for going beyond the ready-made bilateral distributed-behaviour Archetype primitives, that permit to build a custom-specific, controlled as required, load-balancer of one's own wish and taste.

Comment: Although I appreciate you spending time to write all these but I need more specific answers. General on the air explanation or "go talk to maintainers" is not what people come here for. Thanks for pointing out nIoTHREADs though.